# How do I specify the order of plugins (bound to the same phase) in Maven 3?

Tags: scala, plugins, maven, compilation

I have a multi-module Scala project using Maven 3.
I want to make sure that the Scala compiler runs before the Java compiler, both for compile and test-compile phases.

I have tried, in both my parent POM and module POM, listing the plugins in the build section so that the Scala compiler plugin is first, and yet Maven still insists on running the Java compilation first, which fails in some cases where I have mixed source.

I know I can solve this by binding the Scala compilation to process-resources instead of compile, but I'd really prefer to know how I can tell Maven to order the plugins (or whether this is possible).

Here is the part of my parent POM that defines these two plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The child module has its own <plugins> section, but doesn't re-define either of these plugins (just the exec-maven-plugin).

Comment: What does the effective POM say the order is?

Comment: The project is at https://github.com/GrahamLea/SodaTest if anyone wants to clone it down and try out a fix. It's the sodatest-examples-basic-java module that has the problem. (Note that in the committed version everything works because I've bound the scala compilation to the process-resources phases.)

Comment: @Donal: In the effective POM for the module (in the plugins section inside build), the maven-scala-plugin appears before the maven-compiler-plugin. Does the pluginManagement section have a part to play here? Neither of these plugins appear in there.

Comment: Hmm, that's contrary to what I understood the order in a POM to mean, but that can't be helped. :-( I suppose you could try binding it to the generate-sources phase, which is a *bit* of an abuse but if it works…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Maven development team has confirmed](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-dev/201105.mbox/%3C4DC87D9E.5010506@udo.edu%3E) that currently it is not possible to completely control the order of plugin execution within a phase, except by writing your own custom Lifecycle and using a custom Package Type.

I've created [an enhancement request in JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5090) for them to consider fixing this. Please vote for it if this is an issue for you.

It seems for the moment that the 'best practice' workaround for this specific problem (Mixed Java/Scala compilation) is to bind the scala:compile to process-resources and scala:testCompile to process-test-resources, as specified at http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_java.html

Answer (score 1):

you can run the 2 separate goals together and maven will execute the goals in sequence:

```
mvn scala:compile compiler:compile
```

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting idea, and it would work, but then the project wouldn't build for people who didn't know they had to do this. Open source Maven project - people expect (rightly) to be able to run mvn install and have it all work.

Comment: +1 for scala:compile.The good thing is that if you are mixing java and scala the scala compiler plugin compiles java files too. so a simple **mvn scala:compile** will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

To compile a mixed Java/Scala project, it's actually a bit more complicated than *just* compiling one then the other.  Amongst other things, the Scala compiler is able to parse Java files in order to match up signatures for any Java classes that you're using from Scala.  The compiler can essentially do the right thing for you here, but you must first tell it to do so.

Your best bet is to use SBT instead of Maven, as it'll offer many benefits beyond just getting the compilation order right.

If moving away from Maven is not an option, then follow the configuration instructions for the maven-scala-plugin here: http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_java.html

Comment: Hi, Kevin. Thanks for your comments. In Maven, it actually isn't any more complicated than just compiling one after the other. The Scala plugin has all the source paths configured by default so that it 'just works'. Unfortunately, there's a bug in Maven that stops the order of the plugins from being under user control. Your link shows the workaround config, which is the best solution for the moment. Cheers, Graham.

Answer (score -1):

Is the `id` for the maven compiler plugin to `default-compile`?  If not, can you set it and try if it works?

If not, you could update the question with relevant pom snippet and the snippet from the maven run.

Comment: I assume you meant the id of the executions? I actually didn't have any executions for the standard compile plugin, so I added some, with the ID you specified and the corresponding one for the test tree, but it didn't help.